# jquery parsejson undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I currently have the following undefined error in my JavaScript. I'm very new to jQuery and js so any help would be great.

JSON

```
"{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : "p17591307kboph5f57q13bg1iu44.jpeg", "id" : "id"}"
```

Jquery:

```
var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();
    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, res) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(res.response);
        alert( obj.id );
        $('#showfilelist').append("<div id=" + file.id + "><img src='/media/images/galleries/" + _id +"/" + obj.id + "' width='100' height='100' /><br>" + file.name + "<br>(" + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ") <span></span></div>");
    });
```

Comment: is that the JSON data or is it `{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : "p17591307kboph5f57q13bg1iu44.jpeg", "id" : "id"}` that is returned? it should not start with a "

Comment: it is actually this: "{\"jsonrpc\" : \"2.0\", \"result\" : \"p17591307kboph5f57q13bg1iu44.jpeg\", \"id\" : \"id\"}"

Comment: Just a note, but in your JSON the obj.id = "id" and the obj.result = the name of the image. It is not the source of the problem for sure, just a note, that may this one is wrong.

Whould be helpfull if you could debug and check on what object gets you the undefined error?

Comment: What's the result of `res.toSource()` ?

Comment: I get the following response:({response:"\"jsonrpc : 2.0, result : p175a9edmsubg1snrp727djelg4.jpeg, id : id\"", status:200})

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> it is actually this: "{\"jsonrpc\" : \"2.0\", \"result\" :
>   \"p17591307kboph5f57q13bg1iu44.jpeg\", \"id\" : \"id\"}"

I'm starting to believe that the problem is in the file which sends that "JSON" string.
It shouldn't contain those backslashes (`\`).

If you are using PHP , Consider an array and the next function to make a good formatted-json data.

`json_encode`